# Problem with setting size of MDDialog in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, mddialog

Faced the problem of adjusting the parameters of the card and everything that is located on it. I can't set the size of the card I need and besides that, I can't set the sizes of buttons and textfields.

It looks like this on fullscreen:
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReOmi.png)

In small view like this:
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4HNK.png)

But I had to pick balance between kv file and python file.
I want to have 1 size always, without changing on full screen.
Please, tell me where I have mistake.

regcard.kv

```
<RegCard>

    orientation: "vertical"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
    spacing: 30
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 550

    MDBoxLayout:

        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}

        MDIcon:

            icon: "account-plus"
            pos_hint: {"left": 1}
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 50, 50

        MDLabel:

            text: 'Reg'
            font_size: 18
            halign: "left"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1

        MDIconButton:

            icon: "close"
            pos_hint: {"right": 1, "bottom": 1}
            on_release: app.root.get_screen('main').dialog.dismiss()

    MDTextField:

        id: card_first_name

        mode: "rectangle"
        halign: "left"
        hint_text: "Name"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.9}
        size_hint_x: 0.8
        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
        required: True
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        helper_text: "please fill all"

    MDTextField:

        id: card_last_name

        mode: "rectangle"
        halign: "left"
        hint_text: "Surname"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.8}
        size_hint_x: 0.8
        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
        required: True
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        helper_text: "please fill all"

    MDTextField:

        id: card_patronymic

        mode: "rectangle"
        halign: "left"
        hint_text: "Patronymic"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.7}
        size_hint_x: 0.8
        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
        required: True
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        helper_text: "please fill all"

    MDRectangleFlatIconButton:

        id: card_status

        icon: "view-list"
        size_hint_x: 0.85
        text: "Category"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
        on_release: root.open_status_list()
        font_size: 16
        icon_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        text_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)

    MDTextField:

        id: card_phone

        mode: "rectangle"
        halign: "left"
        hint_text: "Phone"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        size_hint_x: 0.8
        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
        required: True
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        helper_text: "please fill all"

    MDRoundFlatIconButton:

        icon: "printer"
        text: "Print badge"

        font_size: 16
        on_release: root.print_badge()
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.4}
        icon_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        text_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        

    MDBoxLayout:

        adaptive_size: True
        orientation: "horizontal"
        spacing: "10dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7, "center_y": 0.5}

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:

            id: button_cancel

            text: "Cancel"
            font_size: 16
            md_bg_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
            on_press: app.root.get_screen('main').dialog.dismiss()

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:

            id: button_next

            text: "Save"
            font_size: 16
            md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            on_press:
                root.save_data()
                if root.check_data(): \
                app.root.get_screen('main').close_menu(); \
                app.root.get_screen('main').find_guest(card_last_name.text)
```

main.kv

```
<MainScreen>:

    name: "main"
    username: username

    MDBoxLayout:

        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        spacing: 20

        MDBoxLayout:

            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            md_bg_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}

            TooltipMDIconButton:

                icon:"account"
                on_release: root.add_user()
                pos_hint: {"left": 1, "top": 1}
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                tooltip_text: "New member"

            TooltipMDIconButton:

                icon:"xml"
                on_release: root.go_url()
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.2}
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                tooltip_text: "Something else"

            TooltipMDIconButton:

                icon:"rocket-launch"
                on_release: root.go_url()
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.4}
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                tooltip_text: "API"


        MDBoxLayout:

            size_hint: (1, None)
            height: 70

            orientation: "horizontal"

            MDRoundFlatIconButton:

                icon: "reload"
                icon_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                text: "Reload"
                font_size: 14
                line_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
                pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.93}
                text_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                on_release: root.update_page()


            MDTextField:

                id: username

                halign: "center"
                icon_right: "magnify"
                hint_text: "Search"
                helper_text: "Enter surname for searching"
                helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.93}
                current_hint_text_color: 0, 0, 0, 0.5
                text_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                line_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                on_text_validate: root.find_guest(username.text)

            MDIconButton:

                icon:"qrcode-scan"
                on_release: root.get_qrcode()
                pos_hint: {"right:": 1, "center_y": 0.93}
                text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color


        ScrollView:

            MDGridLayout:

                id: members_list

                cols: 3
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height

<TooltipMDIconButton@MDIconButton+MDTooltip>
```

py.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout


Window.minimum_width = 1280
Window.minimum_height = 1024

Builder.load_file('main.kv')
Builder.load_file('reg_card.kv')

members = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "phone": "123456",
        "company": "Tester",
        "entry_time": None,
        "entered": False,
        "email": "temp@temp.net",
        "count_entry": None,
        "qrcode": None,
        "category": "Start",
        "locale": "en",
        "published_at": "2022-02-16T14:10:12.529Z",
        "created_at": "2022-02-16T14:10:03.802Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-02-16T14:10:12.556Z",
        "localizations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Eva",
        "last_name": "Green",
        "phone": "007008",
        "company": "Demo",
        "entry_time": None,
        "entered": False,
        "email": "demo@demo.net",
        "count_entry": None,
        "qrcode": None,
        "category": "Middle",
        "locale": "en",
        "published_at": "2022-02-16T14:17:10.249Z",
        "created_at": "2022-02-16T14:17:10.259Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-02-17T10:00:46.889Z",
        "localizations": []
    }
]


class RegCard(MDBoxLayout):

    def open_status_list(self):
        menu_items = [
            {
                "text": f'{item}',
                "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                "on_release": lambda x=f'{item}': self.menu_callback(x),
            }
            for item in ['Junior', 'Middle', 'Senior']
        ]

        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.ids.card_status,
            items=menu_items,
            width_mult=2,
            max_height=148,
            radius=[20, ],
        )
        self.menu.open()

    def print_badge(self):
        print('Printing badge...')

    def menu_callback(self, text_item):
        self.ids.card_status.text = text_item
        self.menu.dismiss()

    def check_data(self):
        if self.ids.card_first_name.text != '' and self.ids.card_last_name.text != '' and \
                self.ids.card_phone.text != '' and self.ids.card_status.text != '':
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def save_data(self):
        print('Data saved')


class MainScreen(MDScreen):

    def fill_screen(self):
        for member in members:
            first_box = TwoLineListItem(
                    text=f'{member.get("first_name")} {member.get("last_name")}',
                    secondary_text=member.get('phone'),
                )

            second_box = TwoLineListItem(
                    text="Категория",
                    secondary_text=member.get('category'),
                    size_hint_x=0.2,
                )
            btn_box = MDIconButton(
                    icon='pencil',
                )

            self.ids.members_list.add_widget(first_box)
            self.ids.members_list.add_widget(second_box)
            self.ids.members_list.add_widget(btn_box)

    def on_enter(self):
        self.update_page()

    def add_user(self):

        self.dialog = None

        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                size_hint=(0.3, None),
                type="custom",
                content_cls=RegCard(),
                radius=[25, ],
                auto_dismiss=False
            )
            self.dialog.open()

    def close_menu(self, *args):
        self.dialog.dismiss()

    def update_page(self):
        self.ids.username.text = ""
        self.ids.members_list.clear_widgets()
        self.fill_screen()


class InvisionApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"

        Window.size = (1280, 1024)

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main'))

        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    InvisionApp().run()
```

After setting card's parameters (thanks to @ApuCoder 's advice) I faced another problem with card (when it opens) like this:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0gex.png)

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: @ApuCoder , thank you for your callback. Question was updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with lagging card was solved this way:

```
class MainScreen(MDScreen):
    dialog = None

    def add_user(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                size_hint=(None, None),
                width=400,
                type="custom",
                content_cls=RegCard(),
                radius=[25, ],
                auto_dismiss=False,
            )
        self.dialog.open()
```

I pulled 'dialog = None' out of every function to the class MainScreen.

Comment: Thanks Yuri Ivanov from kivymd support team!

Answer (score 0):

Since your `RegCard` is inherited from `MDBoxLayout`, you can adjust its children's height automatically (with `adaptive_height` property) or make it large enough (by calculating each child's height) to hold its children properly. With this and some other modification your `reg_card.kv` will look something like this,

```py
<RegCard>

    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "10dp" # Adjust to your need (atyn).
    spacing: "10dp" # atyn.
    adaptive_height: True

    MDBoxLayout:

        orientation: "horizontal"
        spacing: "10dp" # atyn.
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "64dp" # atyn.
#        pos_hint: {"top": 1}

        MDIcon:

            icon: "account-plus"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "center_y": 0.5}
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 50, 50

        MDLabel:

            text: 'Reg'
            font_size: 18
            halign: "left"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1

        MDIconButton:

            icon: "close"
            pos_hint: {"right": 1, "center_y": 0.5}
            on_release: app.root.get_screen('main').dialog.dismiss()

    MDTextField:

        id: card_first_name

        mode: "rectangle"
        halign: "left"
        hint_text: "Name"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.9}
        size_hint_x: 0.8
        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
        required: True
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        helper_text: "please fill all"

    MDTextField:

        id: card_last_name

        mode: "rectangle"
        halign: "left"
        hint_text: "Surname"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.8}
        size_hint_x: 0.8
        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
        required: True
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        helper_text: "please fill all"

    MDTextField:

        id: card_patronymic

        mode: "rectangle"
        halign: "left"
        hint_text: "Patronymic"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.7}
        size_hint_x: 0.8
        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
        required: True
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        helper_text: "please fill all"

    MDRectangleFlatIconButton:

        id: card_status

        icon: "view-list"
        size_hint_x: 0.85
        text: "Category"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
        on_release: root.open_status_list()
        font_size: 16
        icon_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        text_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)

    MDTextField:

        id: card_phone

        mode: "rectangle"
        halign: "left"
        hint_text: "Phone"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        size_hint_x: 0.8
        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1
        required: True
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        helper_text: "please fill all"

    MDRoundFlatIconButton:

        icon: "printer"
        text: "Print badge"

        font_size: 16
        on_release: root.print_badge()
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.4}
        icon_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        text_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        

    MDBoxLayout:

        adaptive_height: True
        orientation: "horizontal"
        spacing: "10dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7, "center_y": 0.5}

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:

            id: button_cancel

            text: "Cancel"
            font_size: 16
            md_bg_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
            on_press: app.root.get_screen('main').dialog.dismiss()

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:

            id: button_next

            text: "Save"
            font_size: 16
            md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            on_press:
                root.save_data()
                if root.check_data(): \
                app.root.get_screen('main').close_menu(); \
                app.root.get_screen('main').find_guest(card_last_name.text)
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, it helps me to set regcard's and editcard's parameters. But I have strange thing. Added screen to main quiestion. Can you give me additional advice please?

Comment: I think that's because you have set `size_hint_y` of the dialog to `None` in `.py`. Try changing or disabling it.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I deleted size_hint_y, but this lag (duration less than 1 second) is still. If I create empty dialog, it works fine. Maybe problem in RegCard? 
Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: However since [**KivyMD**](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is not in their stable version yet, you can keep experimenting with your logic (*like instead of assigning `content_cls` directly you can do something like: `self.dialog.content_cls=RegCard()` or use `Clock` etc.*) to get optimal/expected outcome.